# Is it correct to edit the files inside vendor folder of laravel 5.2 as per our needs?

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, redirect, laravel-5

Im new to laravel and is doing a sample project as study purpose. I had created authentication using the command:

```
php artisan make:auth
```

I had given the redirection link in Authcontroller.php for all successful login/registration as:

```
protected $redirectTo = '/admin';
```

All these things are working fine and My problem is when i try to reset password using the password reset option on laravel 5.2 builtin auth controller, i am able to reset my old password with the new one. but after resetting my password it is getting redirected to a link like examplelaravel.com/home. It is not going to examplelaravel.com/admin as per the redirection link (protected $redirectTo = '/admin';) fgiven by me in Authcontroller.php.

While going through each and every files in my laravel project, i saw a file named vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RedirectsUsers.php which contains a method like:

```
public function redirectPath()
{
    if (property_exists($this, 'redirectPath')) {
        return $this->redirectPath;
    }

    return property_exists($this, 'redirectTo') ? $this->redirectTo : '/home';
}
```

i had changed the /home to /admin in the above said file and my issue regarding the redirection after successful password reset got fixed. But i dont know whether it is the correct method or not?? Is it correct way to edit the files inside the vendor folder like as i did above?? Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: According to what you are saying, it seems you didn't change `$redirectTo` in the `PasswordController`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have set the `$redirectTo` link in your `AuthController` but you haven't set it inside your `PasswordController`.

As the two controllers handle completely different functionality the `$redirectTo` link isn't carried over from one to the other.

To set the `PasswordController` to redirect to your admin route, just add this line in as you have with your `AuthController`:

`protected $redirectTo = '/admin';`

The `redirectPath` function you have found is just checking if the `$redirectTo` path has been set elsewhere, otherwise it will redirect to `/home`. However as it has been said, you shouldn't edit anything inside the `vendor` folder otherwise whenever you run `composer update` it will overwrite any of your changes when the files update.

Comment: Thank you. i didn't found any similar line like `protected $redirectTo = '/home';` inside default PasswordController.php at first. So as you suggested, now i added the line `protected $redirectTo = '/admin';` inside the PasswordController class and it worked perfectly without doing any changes in the vendor folder files. Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

The next time you run `composer update`, any changes made in `vendor` dir will be undone.

You should never touch or mess with `vendor` as it is *immaculate*.